# Show that dihedral group of twice odd order doesn't have a normal subgroup of order $2m$, where $m$ divides $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, dihedral-groups

Let $n \ge 3$. Let $D_n = \langle r,s \rangle$, for $r^n=s^2=1$ and $rs=sr^{-1}$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283071/is-order-of-dihedral-group-part-of-the-definition-or-something-to-be-proven#comment8915138_4283071) $D_n$ (not $D_{2n}$) is the dihedral group of order $2n$.

> Show that if $n$ is odd, then $D_n$ doesn't have a ***(EDIT: )proper*** normal subgroup of order $2m$, where $m$ divides $n$.

---

**Question**: Is there a way to go about doing this without necessarily [knowing all the subgroups of $D_n$ and in particular that when $n$ is odd the only normal subgroups are (cyclic) subgroups of the cyclic subgroup $\langle r \rangle $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484828/normal-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups)?

- Or is there a way to show that when $n$ is odd the only normal subgroups are (cyclic) subgroups of the cyclic subgroup $\langle r \rangle $ without necessarily knowing all the subgroups of $D_n$?
- **Perhaps normal subgroup implies non-intersection with the reflection half $\{s,sr,...,sr^{n-1}\}$?**

---

If everything is allowed, then I'll just pretend [I know all the subgroups of $D_n$ and that when $n$ is odd the only subgroups are (cyclic) subgroups of $\langle r \rangle $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484828/normal-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups) :

Step 1. Assume/Prove the above (which is a BIG thing to assume. see [keith conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf). There's this [simpler version here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446863/is-there-a-simpler-way-of-categorizing-all-the-subgroups-of-d-n).)

Step 2. For $order(r)=n$ and for any $t$ that divides $n$, we have $order(r^t)=\frac{n}{gcd(n,t)}=\frac{n}{t}$.

Step 3. Suppose on the contrary that $D_n$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $2m$. By step 1, $N$ is a (cyclic) subgroup of the cyclic subgroup $\langle r \rangle$.

Step 4: By Step 3, $N = \langle r^d \rangle$, for some $d$ that divides $n$.

Step 5. By Step 2, $order(r^d)=2m$ if and only if $2md=n$.

Step 6. Since n is odd, we have by step 5 that $order(r^d)$ can't be even.

Step 7. Therefore, steps 3-4 and 6 give our required contradiction.

---

Possibly relevant things:

1. Previously, I attempted to exhibit that whether $n$ is odd or even, $D_n$ has subgroups of orders $m$ and $2m$: [Prove dihedral group has subgroup of order $m$ and then of order $2m$, where $m$ divides $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283108/prove-dihedral-group-has-subgroup-of-order-m-and-then-of-order-2m-where-m)
2. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose both the order of $N$ and the index $[G:H]$ are finite and then coprime. Show that $N \subseteq H$.

Comment: @Leo $D_n$ not $D_{2n}$. The order of $D_n$ is $2n$ not $n$

Comment: @Leo Please help in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283456). I try to show we can't have such a normal subgroup even though I don't know all the subgroups of $D_n$

Comment: Oh I was completely lost after all.

Comment: @Leo WAIT NO. YOUR COMMENT HELPED ME REACH CONCLUSION. SEE MY UPDATED ANSWER. THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: Firstly, your problem statement is technically incorrect. $D_n$ does have a normal subgroup of order $2m$ with $m$ dividing $n$, namely $D_n$ itself. So you need to specify *proper* normal subgroup in your problem statement. Secondly, do you know about the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ (sometimes called the derived subgroup $G'$) of a group $G$?

Comment: @Leo oh wait lol i made the same mistake as you. lol. nvm. still, thanks

Comment: @DerekHolt THANK YOU. oh yeah asked instructor. it's supposed to be proper normal subgroup. lol. i know commutator but it wasn't discussed yet in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Smith Kyon, your idea is very good.
If we remove all unnecessary things from your reasoning,
we get a solution to our problem.
It looks something like this.

Let $n$ be odd and let $N$ be a normal subgroup in $D_n$ of order $2m$.

Step 0.
We know that $I=\{s,sr,\ldots,r^{n-1}\}$ is
a complete list of all elements of order $2$ of group $D_n$.

Step 1.
Since $N$ is of even order, we get $N\cap I\neq\varnothing$.
Let $sr^k\in N$.

Step 2.
Since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $D_n$, then
$$
r^t(sr^k)r^{-t}=sr^{k-2t}\in N \hbox{ for all $t\in\mathbb{Z}$}.
$$

Step 3.
Since $n$ is odd, we obtain that the set
$$
\{k-2t\mid t=0,1,\ldots,n-1\}
$$
is a complete residue system modulo $n$.
It follows that $I\subset N$. So $N=D_n$.

Comment: thank you very much kabenyuk! though i think i could've figured this out in time for homework submission had i not been so damn tired already figuring out the proper subgroup thing. but i guess that i could've figured it out (insert stuff i just said) is kinda the point of the 1st part of your answer.

Comment: kabenyuk, is this right also please? [Prove dihedral group has subgroup of order m and then of order 2m, where m divides n.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283108/prove-dihedral-group-has-subgroup-of-order-m-and-then-of-order-2m-where-m)

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to show that when  is odd the only normal [proper] subgroups
> are (cyclic) subgroups of the cyclic subgroup ⟨⟩ without necessarily
> knowing all the subgroups of $D_n$?

Yes-- just check the  character table of $D_n$ (where $n$ is odd).  There are two $1$-dim representations -- the trivial representation and the sign / determinant representation and neither will work.  Using the induced representation / Frobenius Reciprocity to build off cyclic subgroup $H$ generated by $r$, all other representations are 2 dimensional and identically 0 on the 2nd coset $aH$.

Normal subgroups are in the kernel of *some* homomorphism, so the character table tells you that any proper normal subgroup cannot include the second coset $aH$.

In general you can extract an awful lot amount of information from the character table of a group despite not knowing much about the actual group.  And induced representations are relatively straightforward when dealing with index 2 subgroups.

Comment: thanks user8675309 but we don't really have character table, representations, etc. but well i guess i am indeed on the right track to show the only normal subgroups are cyclic subgroups of $\langle r \rangle$. Please help me out in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283456) where I tried to do something along this path.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Didn't care anymore after the mistake of my instructor about the proper normal subgroup. I just answered with saying that proper normal subgroup doesn't intersect the reflections. And then did the rest of the stuff.

---

Wait I think I got it. Let's prove that a normal subgroup $N$ with order $2m$ while $n$ is odd can't intersect the reflections, i.e. we can't have $N \cap \{s,sr,...,sr^{n-1}\} \ne \emptyset$:

Step 1. Suppose on the contrary $N$ intersects the reflections, i.e. $N \cap \{s,sr,...,sr^{n-1}\} \ne \emptyset$. Then $sr^k \in N$, for some $k=0,1,...,m-1$.

Step 2. Because $N$ is normal subgroup, we have that $N$ contains the elements $a(sr^k)a^{-1}$ with $a = s, r$.

1. $sr^{n-k} = (s)(sr^k)(s)^{-1}$
2. $r^{k-2}s = (r)(sr^k)(r)^{-1}$

Step 3. Then because $N$ is a regular subgroup, we have that $N$ contains

$r^{k-2}ssr^{n-k}=r^{k-2}r^{n-k}=r^{n-2}$.

Step 4. Now for $order(r)=n$, we have $order(r^{n-2})=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,n-2)}$. Because $n$ is odd (and because $n \ge 3$), we have [that $\gcd(n,n-2)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038877/prove-gcdn-n2-1-if-n-is-odd-and-2-if-n-is-even). Hence, $order(r^{n-2})=\frac n 1 = n$.

Step 5. By Steps 3-4, we have I think a contradiction with Lagrange's theorem...Or well if this doesn't work just say that all of $\langle r \rangle$ is a subset of $N$. Combined with the $sr^k \in N$, we have the rest of the reflections in $N$ because $sr^i=sr^k(r^{i-k})$. Therefore $D_n \subseteq N$. Hmmm...the exact contradiction is...well it's a contradiction if $m \ne n$.

As for $m = n$, we have $N = D_n$.

QED!